# Codeigniter & SQLite - save session to database not working (ci_session)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, sqlite, pdo

I've just set up CI to work with sqlite via PDO and everything went smoothly. (I can query the sqlite db and all is fine.)

Now I have a problem, I set:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

and problems arise:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\CI\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php on line 193
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0030 151392 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.0109 187664 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\CI\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' ) ..\index.php:202
3 0.0885 669544 Login->__construct( ) ..\CodeIgniter.php:308
4 0.0885 669600 CI_Controller->__construct( ) ..\login.php:7
5 0.0986 793008 CI_Loader->initialize( ) ..\Controller.php:51
6 0.0986 792984 CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader( ) ..\Loader.php:152
7 0.1362 1331192 CI_Loader->library( ) ..\Loader.php:1178
8 0.1363 1331304 CI_Loader->_ci_load_class( ) ..\Loader.php:216
9 0.1445 1412936 CI_Loader->_ci_init_class( ) ..\Loader.php:975
10 0.1462 1414368 CI_Session->__construct( ) ..\Loader.php:1099
11 0.1601 1483408 CI_Session->sess_read( ) ..\Session.php:106
12 0.1731 1486592 CI_DB_active_record->get( ) ..\Session.php:213
13 0.1735 1487800 CI_DB_driver->query( ) ..\DB_active_rec.php:963
14 0.1736 1488824 CI_DB_driver->simple_query( ) ..\DB_driver.php:299
15 0.1736 1488856 CI_DB_pdo_driver->_execute( ) ..\DB_driver.php:453
```

I don't know where the problem is. My sqlite ci_session table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE ci_session (
 session_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 ip_address VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 user_agent VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
 last_activity INT(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 user_data VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

I suppose this is fine (except I didn't include the last line from the original SQL statment):

```
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
```

I'm also pretty sure the problem is not related to this, but just in case: the original MySQL table is located [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) under "Saving Session Data to a Database".

Comment: are you using mysql or SQLlite? you know codeigniter has a database.php file where to set the database driver?

Comment: Sure i know that..i setup the database.php so it uses SQLite and it works like a charm..problems arise when i try to use the Save Session Data to Database option..something goes wrong and it displays what i wrote above..

Comment: which is the ci version? i'm on a 2.1 and that folder called **/pdo/** there is not under **/core/database/drivers** .. there is one called **/sqlite** ! i think you are using old CI version or future one :D

Comment: nha, i'm using the latest CI..maybe you can really help doing a test enabling ci_session save to database..i just tested all the theoretical things about CI version etc etc and i'm a php/CI developer since 5 years now but really can't figure this out :)

Comment: and i'm on CI 2.1.3 (Latest stable release)

Comment: I had this problem last month. I only updated/rename the cookie name.

Comment: Are you autoloading the database library?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CodeIgniter but i want to shed some light on this, the message you're getting is the equivalent to a Null reference exception, that is happening here:

```
CI_DB_pdo_driver->_execute( )
```

As this is part of CodeIgniter, either you may not have set up something, or you're facing a bug on CodeIgniter.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I asked the same question in CI's forum under Code! but haven't got a single reply :P